# How can I call a constructor in my xaml page?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

At first I created my own EditLabel object with a constructor. Now I will implement this element in the xaml code. How can I call the constructor in this xaml code?

```cs
// edit element
class LookupGrid : Grid
    {
        public Label Label = new Label
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation,
            TextColor = ColorHelper.GetTappedColor
        };

        public LookupGrid(string caption)
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(20,0,20,0);
            HeightRequest = 50;
            BackgroundColor = Color.White;

            ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto }, new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star },
            };

            var captionLabel = new Label
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                Text = caption,
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                FontSize = 14
            };

            Children.Add(captionLabel,0,0);
            Children.Add(Label,1,0);
        }
    }
```

```
<!-- xaml file -->
<editElemnts:LookupGrid> </editElements:LookupGrid>
```

Comment: Why you need to extend a Label just to set Color or Text? There is no need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call the constructor from `xaml`. Looking at your code above, to be honest, you don't even need a new control that derives from `Label`; it has the properties already that you *could bind to*. You can however set the default color and text, you are already doing that, why would you need another control to do that same thing?

Comment: The answer is simple. In my main solution I have a StackLayout with 2 children. The first one is  the captionLabel and the second one ist the valueLabel (works for me like a lookup field). And this stackLayout I want to call in the xaml page. You now what I want?

Comment: Why can't you bind to a standard `label` control, then you can change what you want; they are dependency properties already. If the answer is simple why are you asking here for help? What in your *missing code* would justify for you to change the text of a label? Could you update your post to include what you are asking about?

Answer (score 2):

```
<editElemnts:EditLabel x:Name="captionLabel"> 
    <x:Arguments>
        <x:String>dummyString</x:String>
    </x:Arguments>
</editElements:EditLabel>
```